# Password should not start with number

Tags: javascript, passwords

I want that passoword should not start with number but its not working as expected.

```js
var input = prompt("Enter password");
var nums = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
  if (input.charAt(0) != nums[i]) {
    console.log("password is valid");
    break;
  } else
    console.log("Password should not start with number");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your valid password alert is fired immediately every time the first letter is not 0 (the first nums array item). There are multiple ways to do this, but here is a simpler way to check by using isNaN and parseInt functions:

```js
var input = prompt("Enter password");

if (isNaN(parseInt(input[0]))) {
  alert("password is valid");
} else {
  alert("Password should not start with number");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex for validation of password.I hope it will helps you.

```
^[A-Za-z]\w*$
```

or You can also use this regex.

```
^(?![0-9_])\w+$
```

Comment: there is difference in `should not start with numbers` and `should start with alphabets`.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Let's say your input is "2hello".

What your code does is it checks if the first character of your input is different from the elements on nums array.

However, lets iterate the loop once.

i => 0

nums[i] => 0

input.charAt(0) => 2

nums[i] != input.charAt(0) --> true, 2 != 0

Then it is valid.

But let's try this instead:

```
var input = prompt("Enter password");
var nums = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

if (!nums.includes(parseInt(input.charAt(0)))) {
    alert("password is valid");
    break;
}
else 
    alert("Password should not start with number");
```

As you can see, you don't need a for loop. You have a build-in function ("[includes](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes_array.asp)") that checks if you have the character in the array you assigned.

PS: Don't forget to convert your character to integer! As when you type your password, it is a string. See more here: [parseInt](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are breaking inside your for loop. For example, if you enter a password such as `3abc`, your loop will first check if `'3' != 0`. This is true, and so your "valid" alert will execute and `break` out of the for loop.

An alternative solution could be to use `.some()` with `.startsWith()` to check if your input starts with any of the numbers. And then if it does, output the associated result:

```js
const input = prompt("Enter password");
const nums = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

const isValidPassword = !nums.some(n => input.startsWith(n));

if (isValidPassword)
  alert("password is valid");
else
  alert("Password should not start with number");
```

Or, you could simply test if your first character matches a digit by using regular expressions like so:

```js
const [c] = prompt("Enter password");
const nums = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

const isValidPassword = !/[0-9]/.test(c);

if (isValidPassword)
  alert("password is valid");
else
  alert("Password should not start with number");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this regex like this `^[^0-9].*$` to use in your code use something like this.

```
if (/^[^0-9].*$/.test(input)) {
  alert("password is valid");
} else {
  alert("Password should not start with number");
}
```

> **`Regex explanation`**

```
^ => Match from start position of input
[^0-9] => Other then any number & as it's placed at beginning so anything but number
.* => Match any character
$ => This is end of the entire regular expression & tells it should exact match like this
```

Comment: `/^[^0-9]/` is enough.

Comment: This prompts the wrong answer. It prompts the password shouldnt start with a number when the password entered doesn't start with a number. Change [^0-9] to [0-9] or flip the comments. Either way is fine

Answer (score 0):

the following code fixes your algorithm:

```
function isValidPassword(password, blacklistedChars) {
      const passwordFirstChar = password.charAt(0);

      for(const character of blacklistedChars) {
        if (character === passwordFirstChar) {
          return false;
        }
      }

      return true;
}

const blacklist = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];
const validPassword = "secret";
const invalidPassword = "2secret";

console.log("valid password: " + isValidPassword(validPassword, blacklist));
console.log("invalid password: " + isValidPassword(invalidPassword, blacklist));
```

You can also consider using a regular expression, like so:

```
function isValidPassword(password) {
  const invalidPasswordRegex = /^\d/;
  return !invalidPasswordRegex.test(password);
}

const validPassword = "secret";
const invalidPassword = "2secret";

console.log("valid password: " + isValidPassword(validPassword));
console.log("invalid password: " + isValidPassword(invalidPassword));
```